# Clojure reduce function for vector containing mixture vectors and doubles

Tags: vector, clojure, reduce

I would like sum a vector containing a mixture of doubles and vectors. Something like,

`[[1 2 1 [1 2 3]] [1 2 4 [1 1 1]]...]`

That I would like to sum such that I get something like,

`[212 12 444 [11 2 12]]`

Is there an efficient way to do this using core clojure functions like reduce or map?

Comment: How did you get from `[1 2 1 [1 2 3]]` to `212`?

Comment: Incidentally, make sure you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please add the code what you already have tried.  Since the example already is somewhat unclear it would really help, if you would write a few test cases.  Combined with your attempt we then have a failing scenario and can improve from there.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you want to have a function that adds a nested vector structure, so that `(nvadd [1 2 1 [1 2 3]] [1 2 4 [1 1 1]])` evaluates to `[2 4 5 [2 3 4]]`.  You can then `reduce` your vector of such vectors with that function.

```
(defn nvadd [a b]
  (mapv #(if (vector? %1)
           (nvadd %1 %2)
           (+ %1 %2))
        a b))
```

This assumes well-formed input.

Comment: This is much more slick then the solution I came up with, thanks!